# For loop inside a function

Tags: python, function, for-loop, pychart

I'm still learning Python, and I'd love to know a way to make the following work:

```
a_function(
  for n,item in enumerate(list):
    inside_function(code code code,
                    code code code,
                    code code code))
```

So there's a function nested inside another function, and I need to play out the inside function a number of times, but not the outside one. The code I'm working with is not mine so I can't change the way these functions work.

I can edit with the actual code if anyone needs it, it's something from PyChart.

**Edit: actual code:**

```
ar = area.T(y_coord = category_coord.T(data, 0),
            x_grid_style=line_style.gray50_dash1,
            x_grid_interval=chartlength/5, x_range = (0,chartlength),
            x_axis=axis.X(label="X label"),
            y_axis=axis.Y(label="Y label"))

chart_object.set_defaults(interval_bar_plot.T, direction="horizontal",
                          width=5, cluster_sep = 0, data=data)

ar.add_plot(
  for n,item in enumerate(compactlist):
    interval_bar_plot.T(line_styles = [None, None],
                    fill_styles = [fill_style.red, None],
                    label=compactlist[n], cluster=(n,len(compactlist)))
)

can = canvas.default_canvas()
can.set_title("Chromosome comparison")
can.set_author("Foo")
ar.draw()
```

The ar.add_plot function creates a working area in the canvas (as I understand it), while the interval_bar_plot function creates the bars, one by one. So I need multiple interval_bar_plot functions but only the one add_plot, or it simply repeats the first bar n times.

**Edit: and the error:**

```
  File "intvlbar.py", line 105
    for n,item in enumerate(compactlist):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: so what is the problem you are having?

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes. It comes out with an invalid syntax error at the beginning of the for loop.

Comment: The actual code might be useful. The pseudo-code that you posted doesn't make much sense to me. Does the a_function accept parameters? What is "code code code"? What does that code do?

Comment: gotta be a little more specific. I assume `code code code, code code code...` aren't your actual parameters? Can you update your code example with what you actually have? And also give the error.

Comment: Edited with the error and actual code.

Comment: I think the error is in the surrounding code as the line you point to there is OK. You need to provide a bit more context than just that one line of Python :)

Comment: More code would be helpful, are you trying to invoke ar.add_plot with an expression that evaluates to None? Or were you intending to pass it a collection or a lambda? Does interval_bar_plot.T return a new 'T' instance?

Comment: There we go, I've edited with the entire block of code which creates the chart objects (the rest of the code gets data from a .csv file, edits it, and pops it in the data variable). Unfortunately I didn't write any of it, so I'm little help - I just copy-pasted the example code. I only really understand half of it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is pass several bar plot objects to the `add_plot` method (documented in [here](http://home.gna.org/pychart/doc/module-area.html)). One way you can do this is to pass them each explicitly. For example:

```
ar.add_plot(bar1, bar2, bar3)
```

Examples of this are in the sample code sections of the PyChart documentation for [bar plots](http://home.gna.org/pychart/doc/module-bar-plot.html) and [interval bar plots](http://home.gna.org/pychart/doc/module-interval-bar-plot.html), for example.

You do not want to do this because your `compactlist` might be inconveniently long or of varying length between runs. Another option is to use [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). Create a list containing your bar plot objects:

```
bars = [interval_bar_plot.T(line_styles = [None, None],
                            fill_styles = [fill_style.red, None],
                            label=compactlist[n], cluster=(n,len(compactlist)))
        for n,item in enumerate(compactlist)]
```

Now call `add_plot` with your `bars`:

```
ar.add_plot(*bars)
```

Comment: And because I don't see it in the question, the type of loop used in this answer is called a "list comprehension"

Comment: That looked like exactly the sort of thing I needed, but there needs to be no third end paren after `cluster=(n,len(compactlist)`, because that way it only appears to iterate the first `interval_bar_plot` n times. When I delete that end paren, though, it comes up with a syntax error presumably because interval_bar_plot is incomplete.

Comment: @lowercasename I do not understand what you mean. The list comprehension is producing all `n` bar plot objects. Each call to `interval_bar_plot.T` has two variable pieces of information: `compactlist[n]` and `n`. If we take a simpler list comprehension as an example, we can see that it is producing the list with different items. I have no idea what `compactlist` is, but for the example let it be `compactlist = ['a', 'b', 'c']`. Now let `a = [(compactlist[n], n) for n,item in enumerate(compactlist)]`. Doing `print a` produces `[('a', 0), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]`.

Comment: Ah, no, my mistake! I've worked it out and your code works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because the `for` loop does not return anything in itself. But the `for` loop is placed inside the function call `ar.add_plot()` where the parameters should go. So python is telling you "`ar.add_plot()` needs parameters, but this for loop isn't going to give them to me"

What parameters does `ar.add_plot()` need?

You need something closer to this (though this probably isn't correct):

```
ar.add_plot()
for n,item in enumerate(compactlist):
  interval_bar_plot.T(line_styles = [None, None],
        fill_styles = [fill_style.red, None],
        label=compactlist[n], cluster=(n,len(compactlist)
```

Comment: Missing two closing parens on the last line there (one to close `cluster=(n` and on to close `plot.T(`)

Comment: According to the PyChart documentation, `add_plot()` takes plot objects, which would be the `interval_bar_plot()` function. Would it be possible to approach this backwards, and first create a set of `interval_bar_plot`s, then fill `ar.add_plot` with them?